# How can one distinguish between debit card and credit card payments in Paypal DoExpressCheckoutPayment API function?

Tags: api, paypal

We use DoExpressCheckoutPayment API function to do payment authorization.  The DoExpressCheckoutPayment response has ReceiptID field, which is empty if the payment was funded from a Paypal account or is filled if the payment was by credit card.  Is the ReceiptID field also filled if the payment was by debit card?  If so, how can we distinguish a receipt is that is for credit card from a receipt that is for debit card?  Or is there some other way to distinguish debit card payments?  We get a lot of fraudulent transactions with stolen credit cards.  Since credit card payments are likely fraudulent and debit card payments are likely good, we would like to have a way to know whether a payment was from credit card or debit card to help us decide whether to accept the transaction or not.
Thanks

Comment: Kind of the point to use **Express Checkout** - users will be paying with their **Paypal Account** which can be funded by bank acct, credit/debit card/s. Check [eligibility for Seller Protection](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/security/seller-protection-faq) and if so, the distinction shouldn't matter. Hth

Answer (score 3):

No, PayPal does not tell you how one of their accountholders is funding a payment. That information will not be available to you.

If you will permit me to editorialize for a minute, though:

That's a Good Thing, because the reality is much more complex than debit vs. credi. You don't want to try to second-guess all of these possibilities. Payments might be partially funded from multiple sources; have conditional aka backup funding; use "cards" that are neither the debit nor credit networks you are familiar with (e.g. hybrids like China Union Pay, virtual debit cards backed by who-knows-what, ...); various bank draft networks/mechanisms; PayPal lines of credit; etc. In general, PayPal is doing a LOT of sophisticated things to detect fraud and they deliver very low fraud rates for accountholder payments.

Also: if you are processing an accountholder payment (rather than a direct credit card payment), PayPal's seller protection policies replace whatever protections (usually not much!) you would receive from card networks for Card Not Present transactions. These protections do not depend upon what funding the accountholder uses and may be very useful to you. I recommend you read the policies and determine if you can align your business so that most or all of your sales can qualify for these protections.

If your usage cannot be eligible for PayPal Seller Protections, though, then while PayPal still runs their fraud detection they have a pretty limited set of facilities for you to layer on added fraud detection of your own. They will give you a limited amount of information about the accountholder, but as I noted above this does NOT normally include the account's funding source(s).